# How to turn a set of scripts into a unified cli tool

Tags: command-line

So let's say I just created 2 shell scripts:

*a.sh*

```bash
#!/usr/bin/env bash

echo "hello world"
```

*b.sh*

```bash
#!/usr/bin/env bash

NAME="$#"

echo "hello, $NAME"
```

Both are located in the same directory `mycli`.

Now I want to create a cli tool to call those script in an unified way. The result should be something along these lines:

```bash
$ mycli a      # hello world
$ mycli b john # hello, john
```

What is a simple way to achieve this ?

I managed to do it by creating a `mycli.sh` and adding it to the path, but the solution does not seems right, and forwarding arguments is a nightmare. Especially if I want to add nested scripts (`mycli x y z`, where `z.sh` is a script located under `mycli/x/y/z.sh`).

Comment: You are probably talking more about using the functions and getting arguments done with "case".

Comment: What would nested scripts even do, as opposed to just having an `x` that then calls `y` in the same flat include directory?

Comment: Forwarding arguments is not a nightmare; it's `"$@"`.